# How to quickly switch between Classic and Lightning experience?

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

As not all of my users have adopted lightning UI, as admin, I need to switch back and forth from the two UI's in order to understand, and help solve issues.

What is the fastest/easiest way to do it?

e.g.:

- User X notifies me he does not see a field on the Lightning UI
- At the same time I assist someone else on classic UI
- I want to see what user X talks about, without login as him or web-conf him.

Some quick sneak peak, and back to classic (or vice versa)

Comment: what do you mean quickly switch between.. are you looking for any script that will open lightning?

Comment: anything that I can view both UI's at the same time

Comment: Means two user.. 1 user view lightning and another use view classic UI ? or same user view both UI at a time ?

Comment: each user see's what he wants. I, as admin have access to both UI's simultaneously

Comment: If there's no way to do this, this would make a good idea on the success community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found is that once I enable LUI (Lightning UI), I can use both Home links, and just log to the one I want.

On my bookmarks, I keep the links to both homepages, in classic mode, and LUI mode.

[image]

Classic UI is: `https://eu1.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp`

LUI: `https://eu1.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/home`

I can simple click on one to another. (both can be created as home links, and added to left menu)

[image]

I than (for each main object I wanted to work with) created a LUI/Classic link, with the ID as dynamic variable, this allows me to view each object on the alternate UI (remember to select: view in new window).

**Lead object example**

LUI: `/one/one.app#/sObject/{!Lead.Id}/view`

[image]

Classic Link: `/{!Lead.Id}`

[image]

Comment: that everyone knows we can use `/one/one.aap` change url and redirecting to classic to lightning and vice versa.. but As you asked in question use both classic and lightning at a same time.. how that possible?

Comment: "view in classic" is opening in the same window. so it again redirecting to lightning. please help

Answer (score 1):

You have some options here.

First, on the profile layer you can activate the `Lightning experience user` setting.

Second, you can assign a permission set with that option to the individual users.

[image]

I think you can not use classic and LE at the same time. You will need two users ant two browser windows for that.

Comment: Thanks, Lightning is enabled for all org and profiles already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer exactly solve your issue.As I am also a developer so what I do is first I go to lightning experience and keep that tab open. Now in another tab I switch myself to class UI. So in One tab I have lightning experience and in other I have class UI. Keep both tabs open and work in them . It will works.

**Note:** Vice -versa of this does not work. So follow steps exactly. Also before positing this answer i check this again it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In salesforce classic(old UI),at the top corner,click on the name,in the drop down "Switch to Lightning Experience" link will be available to switch to lightning if it is already enabled.If not,go through the link [enter link description here](http://salesforceglobe4u.blogspot.in/2016/07/how-to-switch-from-salesforce-classic.html) to enable it

To switch from Lightning Experience to Salesforce Classic, simply click on your avatar in the top right-hand side of the screen, and click, "Switch to Salesforce Classic":

Answer (score 0):

As the same user if you switch over from Lightning to Classic if you do it in one browser then it will also do it in any other sessions you have open even in other browsers as it holds this at server level.

It really doesn't take long to switch with the drop down menu though so not sure I really get the problem.

Otherwise you will need 2 user accounts and have one in Classic one in Lightning.

Answer (score 0):

I've found if you have 2 browser instances (using Chrome) you're able to keep one in Classic and one in Lightning and both are fully functional. If you close out of the window and reload it will switch to what the other browser is in.

I also liked the bookmark solution above - works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

this extension works for me, try for your use case. I use this chrome extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-datametadata-u/jkmajpplbomebfegjjagbeoblheeehld

you can use this chrome extension to maintain the context of the record when switching from classic to Lightning and vice versa. Select "Open in LEX" option when you are logged into classic. You will also have Classic and Lightning mode for same record in different tabs in case you want to compare.

Select "Open in classic" when you are in Lightning. For both these options to work the user should right click on a valid record which has record Id in the URL.

I saw that if I navigate in those tabs, both the tabs maintain classic and lightning experience for the same user without overriding the other.